# How to prevent menu showing before it's fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good evening, Is there way how to prevent showing all elements inside nested side menu after click or refresh. What i need is only show elements inside menu or submenu where I click ? Website: [link](http://www.odsavacky.cz/produkty/) . Thank you very much.

Jquery:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('http://www.odsavacky.cz/blog/wpcproduct/') != -1 ){
        $('.arrows_list1-1 li ul').hide();
        var prev_url = document.referrer;
        var $current = $('.arrows_list1-1 li a[href="' + prev_url + '"]');
        $current.parents('.sub-menu').show();
        $current.next('.sub-menu').show();    
    }else if(window.location.href.indexOf('/page/') != -1){
        $('.arrows_list1-1 li ul').hide();
        var page_url = window.location.href.split("/").slice(0,5).join("/");
        page_url = page_url + "/";
        var $current = $('.arrows_list1-1 li a[href="' + page_url + '"]');
        $current.parents('.sub-menu').show();
        $current.next('.sub-menu').show();    
    }else{  
        $('.arrows_list1-1 li ul').hide();
        $('.arrows_list1-1 li').click(function(ev) {
            $(this).find('>ul').show();
            ev.stopPropagation();
        });

        var url = window.location.href;
        var $current = $('.arrows_list1-1 li a[href="' + url + '"]');
        $current.parents('.sub-menu').show();
        $current.next('.sub-menu').show();
    }
```

Comment: Instead of showing all elements inside, you want it... do what?

Comment: I want showing items but only items inside that menu or submenu where I click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several ways to do this. But I can recommend you to use this one:

Add this `css` to your page

```
body:not(.loaded) ul.sub-menu
{
  display:none;
}
```

Then after all your menu code has executed, add:

```
$('body').addClass('loaded');
```

It will hide the sub-menus until your entire script has been executed;

**UPGRADE**

I didn't understand how that you know which `ul` elements to show based on the page URL, but you do (right?).

Use your logic again to create a css rule that math only what you want to hide, and append this css before the page loading.

Right after your last `<ul>` add something like this:

```
<script>
/** FIRST, use your magic to get the li element thats currently selected **/
var currentlySelectedItem = $('.arrows_list1-1 li a[href="' + MAGIC MAGIC + '"]');
var alwaysShowThisGuy = $currentlySelectedItem.parent().parent(); //Should return a <ul>

//Now the css
style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerHTML = "
    body:not(.loaded) ul.sub-menu:not(#"+ $alwaysShowThisGuy.id +")
    {
      display:none;
    }
";
style.type = 'text/css';

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
</script>
```

Evil sorcery huh?!

Comment: Works like a charm. Is there upgrade ? How to do it without closing that menu where I am ?